# Open source commenting systems for static pages - alternatives to Juvia?

Tags: comments, self-hosted

Comments can be invaluable, and in fact they often are, being more interesting or insightful than the commented story. Sites like [LWN](http://lwn.net/), [HN](http://news.ycombinator.com/) or [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com) often stands as proofs. So? Comments are precious and you should treat them with care.

It may sound a bit cliche, but by visiting various sites and blogs I can tell that a lot of people just don't care, as they're using external solutions like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) and [IntenseDebate](http://intensedebate.com/). Such services surely ease going with static blog platforms and other sites, but... They take comments of your site visitors from you. They "deprive" you of full comment control. It's only up to you whether you agree to hold comments outside of your site. I have mixed feelings about choosing this *easy* way.

That's why I'm here and asking you, dear users, about alternative open source solution that anyone can host on their own and use from their static pages. (It would be best if Markdown support was already built-in in them.) It's not rocket science to build such system, but if there are good ones already available, I think we could just use them instead of reinventing the wheel (at least for now :>).

**Do you know any open source commenting systems for static pages besides [Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia)? What is the best one in terms of features and which one would you recommend?**

Juvia looks ok, but I would prefer something lighter, maybe nodejs-based project. Even supporting only 1 site would be enough.

Comment: I asked the question ~8 hours ago at HN (http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4125787), but it strangely went down to 5th  page of [/ask](http://news.ycombinator.com/ask). Maybe because Disqus is YC offspring, who knows? ;)

Comment: Downvoter: Could you explain why you did what you did? I'm really curious of your reasoning.

Comment: I've found [comment-it](http://code.google.com/p/comment-it/), another Rails-based solution (relatively heavy, I would say), but demos aren't working, so don't know how usable it is.

Comment: If you're using [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) in the back, then [Static Comments Plugin for Jekyll](https://github.com/mpalmer/jekyll-static-comments) looks like a sensible solution.

Comment: For node.js there is [Comments](https://github.com/pvorb/node-comments) module, but unfortunately relying solely on mongodb and lacking out-of-the-box ready-to-use scaffolding and simple snippet for static pages.

Comment: There is also [talkatv](http://talka.tv/) ([github repo](https://github.com/talkatv/talkatv/)) done in Python with the help of Flask.

Comment: I just published [Debiki Embedded Comments](http://www.debiki.com/embedded-comments), which you might want to consider. It has Wiki-like features; it uses a novel 2D layout that hopefully contributes to a more varied discussion; and it has various features intended to save people's time. It's open source under the AGPL license. It runs on the JVM and uses PostgreSQL.